# Convert.ToDateTime PHP Equivalent

Tags: php, asp.net, datetime

Trying to understand what `Convert.ToDateTime` is doing here exactly, Because this seems strange to me.  Looking at ASP.NET Code and need to convert over using PHP, but how does this define an All Day Event exactly?

```
if (_StartTime == Convert.ToDateTime("2000-01-01 12:34:56.000") && _EndTime == Convert.ToDateTime("2000-01-01 12:34:56.000"))
    return "All Day Event";
```

Basically, am wondering how to convert this using php, Seems kinda odd that the year is back in 2000, and not the current year.  What is `Convert.ToDateTime` doing here exactly?

Is this saying that `_StartTime == '2000-01-01 12:34:56.000'`?

Comment: DateTime::createFromFormat(),This function is an alias of: DateTime::createFromFormat()

Comment: Aww, ok, thanks, but why would it be checking for a day in the past?  `_StartTime` will never equal that date given in year 2000.  Is this saying that `_StartTime == '2000-01-01 12:34:56.000'`?

Comment: hmmm yes absolutly

Comment: Ok, thanks, that's all what I thought.  Just needed confirmation here.  Ridiculous Code here!